# How to retrieve S3 objects using only its name, not a path?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `Java SDK`. When I Retrieve S3 Objects using `S3ObjectSummaries.getKey()` it retrieves data in a single row such as:

```
/MyReport/20160201-20160301/141c6a9a-a688-4b80-8a21-a8fa3ee0e49f/MyReport-1.csv.zip
```

So how can I retrieve data with only its name, not a path ?

Comment: Please reply me if anyone know

Answer (score 1):

You always need the whole pathname (key) to retrieve the object.

If you just have the string `MyReport-1.csv.zip`, you'll need to call [`AmazonS3Client.listObjects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest)) and find the object summary with a key that ends with `MyReport-1.csv.zip`.